# Regression where the matrix is drawn from a known distribution

Tags: regression, distributions, bayesian, expectation-maximization, approximate-inference

I need to estimate the vector x, where Ax = b, given b is observed data and the columns in the matrix A are drawn from a known distribution. a and b are both formed of positive integers (or zero).

For example, the first column in A is given by a multinomial distribution with probabilities [0.54, 0.43, 0.03, 0], that is to say, for each of x_1 draws, the column will be [1, 0, 0, 0] with probability 0.54, [0, 1, 0, 0] with probability 0.43 as so on. Each column has different probabilities. So if the elements of x and b are large, A will tend to the probabilities, but we can assume they are not.

To give some context: the length of x and b is around 30, it's to infer a daily count of events from a set of observations, where there is a delay of a number of days between the event and observation and we know the distribution of the delay. So in the above example, the second column of A will be given by the probabilities [0, 0.54, 0.43, 0.03].

Comment: Since you don't posit any error in the relation $Ax=b,$ nothing prevents you from applying linear algebra to find the solutions.  This leads me to suspect you haven't fully explained your situation.

Comment: Well, the exact value of A is unknown, I just know the distribution each of its columns are generated from. Since I’m only drawing a small number of samples, the weights are unlikely to be the same as the probabilities.

Comment: The other problem with using something like non-negative least squared or other constrained optimisation techniques here is that they will give a sparse solution, which is not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be respecified as:
$$
p(x_{tr}) = \theta_{t} \beta_{tr}
$$

With the vectors b and x in the original question given by $\textbf{b} = \sum_{t} x_{tr} $ and $ \textbf{x} = \sum_{r} x_{tr} $

The likelihood can be stated as:
$$
p(X|\theta, \beta) = Z \prod_{tr} (\theta_{t} \beta_{tr})^{x_{tr}}
$$
Estimates for x and theta (beta is known in this case) can then be obtained using the Expectation Maximisation algorithm.